# Define an element with attribute and optional value

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

How do I create an xsd that can validate either of the following two examples?

```
<element attribute="attribute-value" />
```

and

```
<element attribute="attribute-value">element-value</element>
```

Comment: Hi Louis, another way to find answers to similar questions is to use a tool that would take in your XML snippet and infer from it an XML Schema file. Virtually every tool that handles XML and XSD reasonably, should have the ability to infer an XSD from an XML. I am also recommeding that if you're going to deal with XML and XSD, you will be better off to use a specialized tool... more like trying to teach you how to fish...

Comment: Hi Louis, can you mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xs:schema id="test"
      targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/test.xsd"
      elementFormDefault="qualified"
      xmlns="http://tempuri.org/test.xsd"
      xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/test.xsd"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  >
    <xs:complexType name="element_type">
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="attribute" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="root">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="element" type="element_type">
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

This assumes that the attribute isn't required.

Comment: if you don't want the root element, then replace the second half with just `<xs:element name="element" type="element_type"></xs:element>`

Comment: <xs:attribute name="attribute" type="xs:string" **use="required"** />

Answer (score 1):

You would use `xsd:simpleContent` for this. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_simpleContent.asp) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I added some validation parameters as follows:

```
<xsd:element name="element">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="OptionalString">
            <xsd:attribute name="row" type="xsd:positiveInteger"
                use="required" />
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:simpleType name="OptionalString">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:minLength value="0" />         
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Would this be different from the solution proposed above?