# Union of xs:dateTime and xs:string?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am using below format in XSD for accepting both string and datetime format for a tag

```
<xs:simpleType name="dateTime-or-string">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:dateTime xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType  name="CustomDate">
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="dateTime-or-string">
                    <xs:attribute name="nullable" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="StartDate" type="CustomDate">
```

Please help if this is incorrect.

My tag will be like this:

```
<lastdate nullable="true"/> or <lastdate>2015-08-05+02:00</lastdate>
```

Comment: this might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796258/define-an-xsd-element-which-can-be-a-datetime-or-empty-with-an-attribute

Comment: One potential complication:  if you want `<lastdate>2015-08-05+02:00</lastdate>` to be matched as a date, you probably want xs:date in the union, and not just xs:dateTime.  Also, your type declares no attribute named `nullable` -- are you thinking of `xsi:nil`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `xs:dateTime` is a strict subset of `xs:string`, there's no need to union the two types together.  You can just use `xs:string` by itself.

Comment: True, as regards the set of XML documents accepted as valid.  Not true, as regards the information generated by the process of validation (the post-schema-validation infoset or PSVI) and potentially available to downstream processors:  a consumer of documents might route documents to one queue, or process them in one way, if the value of `lastdate` is recognized as an instance of xs:dateTime, and to a different queue / in a different way otherwise.  It can also make a difference to human readers of the schema:  it can help to set expectations.

Comment: So, use a union of `xs:dateTime` and `xs:string` when (1) you'd like to leverage wholly imaginary (but theoretically possible) PSVI processing, or (2) you'd like to communicate that a dateTime oughta go here, but, what da hell, a string's good enuff.     :-)

Comment: You're not as impressed as I hoped you'd be :), but yes, I think you got the gist.  I'm not certain the PSVI processing is imaginary:  last time I looked I thought Xerces provided access to the PSVI, and any schema-aware XPath or XSLT processor will also assign different types to the `lastdate` element.  And real-world vocabularies do occasionally say things like "if possible, use xs:date, and the value will be handled appropriately; non-date strings will be accepted as valid, because we have no choice, but they won't be processed as dates."

Comment: PSVI *creation* is real -- was doubting whether such a union expressed in the PSVI would be *processed/used* in any way of consequence.  Nevertheless, I grant you the point and thank you for your always insightful and thoroughly enjoyable observations.